# Reading only part of mp4 file from OpenCV's videocapture

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I want to read only a part of mp4 file using Videocapture, this is my sample code to read whole mp4 in Videocapture object.

```
VideoCapture cap("demo.mp4");
```

Is it possible to read only a part of file ,i.e. from 10 seconds to 50 seconds.
As the demo.mp4 is much big file so I don't want to load the remaining part in object which increases memory usage of program.

I also used `cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame);` ,this works but it doesn't solve the memory usage issue.

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by saying the *"I don't want to load the remaining part"* ? Do you mean you just wanna start from 10 sec or you dont wanna read after 50 sec ?

Comment: Means when we create the object ,it stores whole mp4 file in memory. In this case I only want to load only required part of  mp4 file in timestamps of 10 sec to 50 sec  ,so the program consumes less memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cut your video with `ffmpeg` before opening with `VideoCapture`. For example, to get 40 seconds fragment from 00:10 to 00:50, the command is

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' -ss '00:00:10' -t '00:00:40' output.mp4
```